# Filter getAll query results

Tags: java, xodus

This is how to limit the query of Entities using Xodus API:

```
final EntityIterable allUsers = txn.getAll(storeName).skip(skip).take(limit);
```

Question, say the entities stored in the database range from 100k to 500k records, is there a way to filter result based on specific `Entity` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `EntityIterable` with entities having a property equal to a specific value ([Searching by Property Value](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#searching-by-property-value)). E.g., find users with specified login name (property "login"):

```
final EntityIterable users = txn.find("User", "login", loginName);
```

Also you can create an `EntityIterable` with entities having a property value in specified range ([Searching in Range of Property Values](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#searching-in-range-of-property-values)). E.g., find users whose age is in the range of [17-23], inclusively:

```
final EntityIterable students = txn.find("User", "age", 17, 23);
```